# Definition of the polarization of a light beam due to the Kerr effect in fourier- and real space

Tags: optics, non-linear-optics

During my literature review of linear and non-linear optics I found the linear polarization acting on light usually defined as
$$\hat{P}=\varepsilon_0\chi^{(1)}\hat{E}$$
with $\hat{E}$ the electric field in the spectral space. Similarly, the definition for the third-order polarization is
$$\hat{P}=\varepsilon_0\chi^{(3)}\hat{E}^3$$
Nevertheless, I saw several papers which defined the third-order non-linear polarization as
$$P=\varepsilon_0\chi^{(3)}E^3$$
i.e. with the field in the temporal representation, not in the spectral representation. Nevertheless, when I try to convert the equation from the spectral form to the temporal form, I get
$$\begin{align}
F(P)&=\hat{F}\\
&=F(\varepsilon_0\chi^{(3)}E^3)\\
&=\varepsilon_0\chi^{(3)}F(E^3)\text{ after }F(a\cdot f(t))=a\cdot\hat{f}\\
&=\varepsilon_0\chi^{(3)}(\hat{E}*\hat{E}*\hat{E})\\
&\neq\varepsilon_0\chi^{(3)}\hat{E}^3
\end{align}$$
Therefore, I was wondering if I made a mistake during the calculation, or if the sources which give me the equation in the temporal form are wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Polarization is usually given in time, not in frequency as you state. Third harmonic generation is $E^3$ in time or three way convolution in frequency domain.

Comment: When considering f.ex. "Handbook of optics IV, OSA, chapter 17", they give the polarization in the spectral domain, thus I was confused about that.

Comment: I am not familiar with that book. I usually refer to Boyd "Nonlinear optics" for most of my nonlinear optics.

Comment: Assumed I am given the values for $\chi$ as $\chi=\chi^{(3)}(\omega)$, I think the best approach would be to first calculate $E^3$, then transform it to $\widehat{E^3}$, and finally calculate $\hat{P}=\varepsilon_0\chi^{(3)}(\omega)\widehat{E^3}$. Would that be the correct approach?

Comment: I think yes. I do not see why that would be wrong. We typically calculate THG in time domain because its much less computationally intensive.

Comment: I can imagine, but in that case I do not know how to combine $E(t)$ and $\chi(\omega)$, thus I assume that I have to convert the field from the temporal to the spectral range.